# Integration of a function with double argument ignores functional dependence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So, integration

> Integrate[f[x][y], x]

outputs

> x f[x][y]

Is this a bug or a feature? I expect, of course,

> Integrate[f[x][y],x]

Comment: On the other hand `Integrate[f[y][x], x]` is left unevaluated. So *Integrate* is only looking at the "most-sub" sub-value.

Comment: The same as : `Integrate[y, x] /. y -> f[x][y]`.It's not a bug or  feature.